# Why does it take so long to attend flags?

Tags: discussion, moderation

So I flagged a post yesterday and it still has not been attended to. This is quite unusual since this is a very active SE site.

Should this SE have more moderators? Should the moderators be from different time zones for quicker resolution?

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 active mods, and looks like each of us checks in maybe a couple times per week. I don't know if it's reasonable to expect flags to be answered within a day, and don't see that this is meaningfully harming the site. Right? However, I would also like to add more mods.

Comment: Wouldn't say it's a problem though it was significantly more than a day probably, but in an active site flags will probably tend to accumulate exponentially...So quicker resolution might be better since it'll give moderators more time to scrutinize...Just for the future

Comment: We should make you a moderator :)

Comment: This stack is a ticking bomb.. It'll explode very soon

Comment: Stack of what? what are you worried about, concretely?